# What is this place in County of York on UK War Office Marriage Record?

Tags: 19th-century, marriage-records, palaeography, united-kingdom, yorkshire

I am indexing an image on FamilySearch for UK War Office Registers, Soldier Records, 1772-1935. This text in this image is the place of a marriage that took place on Dec, 11, 1825.

I can make out the bottom text, which says 'County of York' but I can't quite make out the top text. I can tell it starts with 'L' and possibly has 'the' at the end.

[image]

Comment: I see you have a lot of questions where you haven't selected an answer. Please don't forget to mark  an answer as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It says "Leeds in the County of York"

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, its "Leeds in the County of York"

In case you're not familiar with the UK, Leeds is a large city in West Yorkshire.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeds

Comment: That answer has already been given.